# Android actionsheet should display half the screen as in iOS

Tags: android

I am trying to have an actionsheet in Android just like in ios. Tried translate animation to get action sheet from bottom of the screen to half the screen but it is occupying full space. Here is the code.

Defined one style in styles.xml

```
 <style name="DialogAnimation">
  <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/bottom_up</item>
  <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/top_down</item>
 </style>
```

bottom_up.xml in res/anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <translate android:fromYDelta="75%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
        android:fillAfter="true"
     android:duration="500"/>
    </set>
```

top_down.xml in res/anim folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:fillAfter="true" android:duration="500" />
    </set>
```

In activity

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActionSheetDemoActivity.this);
                              dialog.setContentView(R.layout.actionsheet);
                              dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;  
                              dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().width = width;
                                Log.i(tag, "Action Sheet created");

                                dialog.show();
                                dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

                        }
                    });
                    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                    width = metrics.widthPixels;
                    Log.i(tag, "Height : "+metrics.heightPixels+" Width : "+width);
                    params = getWindow().getAttributes();
                    params.width = width;
```

But am getting actionsheet to fullheight. Just need it half of the screen.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are trying to implement?

Comment: am unable to post image need 10 reputation for that..

Comment: Please upload the screenshot in a image sharing site and share the link here.

Comment: Hey here is the url http://oi60.tinypic.com/2mwij5e.jpg

Comment: am getting that dialog full screen but it should be half the screen

Comment: If you found an answer, please update. thanks. @gowrip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get the display dimension using `WindowManager` then simply set the dialog height as half of the screen,

```
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActionSheetDemoActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.actionsheet);
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height/2);
        dialog.show();
```

This will show the dialog in half screen of the screen instead of full. Hope this will help!

Comment: yes thankyou got that but am getting margins on all sides didn't set any margin in xml but getting margins for dialog..